# Ansible - Take some variable values from one host and use them in another host

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a playbook that contains the two separate hosts one is 'localhost' and another is 'xyz'.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt: 
    - name: "value" 
      prompt: "Enter your value" 
      private: yes
  roles:
    - a
###

- name: Define xyz
  hosts: xyz

  roles:
    - a
    - b
```

When we run the above playbook then in 'localhost' var_promot take the values from the user and after that, I want to use those values in the 'xyz' host roles in shell commands.

Currently, Inside 'a' role I have this type of code but it gives me an error.

```
- name: echo
  shell: " echo {{ value | urlencode }}"
  register: sout
```

Any idea how to do that or any other way for it?

Answer (score 1):

Neither *vars_prompt* nor *roles* is needed to reproduce the problem. Use simple *vars* and *tasks* instead. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var: foo
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var

- hosts: xyz
  vars:
    test_var: "{{ hostvars.localhost.test_var }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives (debug output only)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: foo

ok: [xyz] => 
  test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

The variable *test_var* was declared in the first play and assigned to the host *localhost*. To use the variable in another host the dictionary  [*hostvars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) is needed. But, the problem is that the variable *test_var* was not "instantiated". This means the variable was not included in the *hostvars*. Let's test it

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var: foo
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.test_var

- hosts: xyz
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.test_var
```

gives (debug output only)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: foo

ok: [localhost] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

ok: [xyz] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

The problem will disappear when *-e, --extra-vars* is used

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e test_var=bar
```

gives (debug output only)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: bar

ok: [localhost] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: bar

ok: [xyz] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: bar
```

To fix the problem for [other sources of variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) "instantiate" the variable in the first play. Use *set_fact*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var: foo
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.test_var
    - set_fact:
        test_var: "{{ test_var }}"
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.test_var

- hosts: xyz
  vars:
    test_var: "{{ hostvars.localhost.test_var }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives (debug output only)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: foo

ok: [localhost] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

ok: [localhost] => 
  hostvars.localhost.test_var: foo

ok: [xyz] => 
  test_var: foo
```

Test other sources, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/localhost 
test_var: foo
```

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - set_fact:
        test_var: "{{ test_var }}"

- hosts: xyz
  vars:
    test_var: "{{ hostvars.localhost.test_var }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives (debug output only)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: foo

ok: [xyz] => 
  test_var: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

in first playbook, you could use a task which creates a dummy host `variable_holder` and use a shared var: (use the module `add_host`)

```
- name: add variables to dummy host
  add_host:
    name: "variable_holder"
    shared_variable:  "{{ value }}"
```

and in second play, you just recall the var shared

```
- name: Define xyz
  hosts: xyz
  vars:
    value: "{{ hostvars['variable_holder']['shared_variable'] }}"
```

the 2 plays have to be in same playbook you launch....